# Unable to generate c# using xsd.exe from a excel XML file

Tags: c#, excel, xml, xsd.exe

When I try to create c# classes using XSD.exe from a excel file saved as XML I get the following errors:

C:\tmp>xsd /c UMUC_0316210400_File2Return001.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.8.3928.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Error: There was an error processing 'UMUC_0316210400_File2Return001.xml'.

- Could not find file 'C:\tmp\UMUC_0316210400_File2Return001.xml'.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

C:\tmp>xsd /c UMUC_0308211948_File2Return001.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.8.3928.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\tmp\UMUC_0308211948_File2Return001.xsd'.

C:\tmp>xsd /c UMUC_0308211948_File2Return001.xsd
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.8.3928.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office:DocumentProperties' element is not declared. Line 8, position 10.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office:OfficeDocumentSettings' element is not declared. Line 9, position 10.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel:ExcelWorkbook' element is not declared. Line 10, position 10.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel:FullColumns' attribute is not declared. Line 83, position 20.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel:FullRows' attribute is not declared. Line 84, position 20.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel:WorksheetOptions' element is not declared. Line 88, position 16.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel:Family' attribute is not declared. Line 31, position 26.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'UMUC_0308211948_File2Return001'.

- The element 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office:DocumentProperties' is missing.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

C:\tmp>

Any help would be very much apreciated!

Comment: Your schema is not complete.  You need to add additional schemas to the one you are using with an INCLUDE.  Many schema have optional parts which only some user will need.  Rather than create one very large schema that all user can use they choose to have child schemas and let the users edit the main schema by adding includes for the optional sections.

Comment: The xsd tool is designed to work with complete schemas.  Not all schemas are complete.  Some schemas have optional sections and others have include statements for child schemas.  The best way to proceed is to open the schema with notepad and see if there are any includes (you may be missing a child schema) or if there are any comments near the missing element.  The xsd too has an option /element which will allow you to generate classes for sections of the schema instead of entire schema.  Sometimes to get the xsd tool to work you need to edit the schema.